# What's going on in this piece of code in assembler? (dword ptr[rbp + 48] ...)

Tags: c#, assembly, dll, x86-64, cpu-registers

I'm analyzing someone's project to convert the image to sepia. I don't understand what's going on in this piece of code that is called as a DLL from C#.

```
.CODE
sepia proc          
    mov         ebx, dword ptr[rbp + 48]    
    mov         r11, rbx                    
    mov         ebx, dword ptr[rbp + 56]    
    mov         r10, rbx                    
    movdqu      xmm1, oword ptr[rdx]        
    movdqu      xmm2, oword ptr[r8]         
    movdqu      xmm3, oword ptr[r9]             

// ... more code ...
```

And here calling the DLL from C# ...

```
  [DllImport("DLL_ASM.dll", EntryPoint = "sepia")]
        private static extern void SepiaAsmAlgorithm(
            float[] pixels, float[] sepiaRates, 
            float[] rgbRates, float[] array255, int startIndex, int endIndex);
```

What this code means

```
ebx, dword ptr [rbp + 48]
```

and why is the value then assigned from the rbx register to r11, since the above entry was made to the ebx register?

Comment: Looks like missed optimization. Could have loaded `r11` directly instead of going through `ebx`. Anyway, `[rbp+48]` is the 5th argument, `startIndex` and `[rbp+56]` is the 6th, the `endIndex`. See the [calling convention documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention)

Comment: [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) explains what writing EDX and reading RDX does.

Comment: But why is +48 and +56 here?

Comment: Because that's where the 5th and 6th arguments are, assuming `rbp` has been set up as a frame pointer.